# How do you compute a masked mean for each row of a 2D tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, mean

I have a 2D tensor like this:

```
[[1. 0. 0. 2. 1. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [2. 0. 2. 1. 1. 3. 0.]]
```

I would like to compute the mean of every nonzero element in each row, so the result would be:

```
[1.25 1.   1.8 ]
```

How can I do that with TensorFlow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of computing per-row masked means is using [`tf.math.unsorted_segment_mean`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/unsorted_segment_mean). Essentially, you can have one segment id per row, then replace the segment id for masked elements with an extra one.

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    x = tf.constant([[1., 0., 0., 2., 1., 0., 1.],
                     [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
                     [2., 0., 2., 1., 1., 3., 0.]], tf.float32)
    s = tf.shape(x)
    num_rows = s[0]
    num_cols = s[1]
    # Mask for selected elements
    mask = tf.not_equal(x, 0)
    # Make per-row ids
    row_id = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(tf.range(num_rows), 1), [1, num_cols])
    # Id is replaced for masked elements
    seg_id = tf.where(mask, row_id, num_rows * tf.ones_like(row_id))
    # Take segmented mean discarding last value (mean of masked elements)
    out = tf.math.unsorted_segment_mean(tf.reshape(x, [-1]), tf.reshape(seg_id, [-1]),
                                        num_rows + 1)[:-1]
    print(sess.run(out))
    # [1.25 1.   1.8 ]
```

However, since in this case the mask is precisely for elements that are nonzero, you can also just use [`tf.math.count_nonzero`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/count_nonzero):

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    x = tf.constant([[1., 0., 0., 2., 1., 0., 1.],
                     [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
                     [2., 0., 2., 1., 1., 3., 0.]], tf.float32)
    x_sum = tf.reduce_sum(x, axis=1)
    x_count = tf.cast(tf.count_nonzero(x, axis=1), x.dtype)
    # Using maximum avoids problems when all elements are zero
    out = x_sum / tf.maximum(x_count, 1)
    print(sess.run(out))
    # [1.25 1.   1.8 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `tf.map_fn` to achieve this:

```py
x = tf.constant([[1., 0., 0., 2., 1., 0., 1.],
                 [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
                 [2., 0., 2., 1., 1., 3., 0.]], tf.float32)
def mean(row):
  mask = tf.not_equal(row, 0.0)
  filtered = tf.boolean_mask(row, mask)
  return tf.reduce_mean(filtered)

out = tf.map_fn(mean, x)
```

Comment: I don't know how this compares to jdehesa's comprehensive (upvoted!) answer in terms of calculation speed (Happy to confess I didnt know about `tf.math.count_nonzero` or `tf.math.unsorted_segment_mean` at all!). I post it here as a more generic way of doing "this sort of thing" that I find useful

Comment: Thanks, usually `tf.map_fn` is not very fast, but `tf.math.unsorted_segment_mean` is not too quick either, so it's worth comparing. Anyway yes, it's a good generic approach for similar problems.